# Find out balance qty on each row between sale and purchase qty

Tags: mysql

I need help to find out balance qty of products qty after minus sale qty in MySql query. Here is my query:

```
SELECT 
eng_stock.doc_id, 
eng_vouchers_detail.prod_id, 
GREATEST(
eng_stock.purch_date, 
eng_stock.sale_date
) AS vouch_date, 
eng_vouchers_detail.purch_qty, 
eng_vouchers_detail.sale_qty, 
GREATEST(
eng_stock.supplier, 
eng_stock.customer
) AS cust_sup, 
eng_stock.report_link 
FROM eng_stock 
LEFT JOIN
eng_vouchers_detail 
ON eng_stock.doc_id = eng_vouchers_detail.doc_id
WHERE eng_vouchers_detail.prod_id = 43
ORDER BY vouch_date
```

[and here is result of this query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Tari.png)

Please help me to resolve this issue

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT
eng_stock.doc_id,
eng_vouchers_detail.prod_id,
GREATEST(
    eng_stock.purch_date,
    eng_stock.sale_date
) AS vouch_date,
eng_vouchers_detail.purch_qty,
eng_vouchers_detail.sale_qty,
eng_stock.report_link,
sum(eng_vouchers_detail.purch_qty) AS p_sum,
sum(eng_vouchers_detail.sale_qty) AS s_sum
FROM
    eng_stock
LEFT JOIN eng_vouchers_detail ON eng_stock.doc_id = eng_vouchers_detail.doc_id
    eng_vouchers_detail.prod_id = 43
WHERE
GROUP BY eng_stock.doc_id
ORDER BY
    vouch_date
```

If it is now what you need, please provide some sample data of your tables.

Comment: Now, I have revised my query please now revise yours. and for better understanding see the attached result image in my post

Comment: I am sorry but I cannot understand you data structure from the snapshot. 
Please provide some simple sample.